# Kotlin Polymorphic deserialization not deserializing values

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, kotlinx.serialization

I'm trying to deserialize JSON into different sealed subclasses, the class mappings work, but the actual values are all null

Example1:

```
{
  "eventName": "SUCCESS",
  "productName": "BLAH"
}
```

Example2:

```
{
  "eventName": "FAILURE",
  "productName": "BLAH",
  "error": "Something went wrong"
}
```

The base sealed class looks like this:

```
@ExperimentalSerializationApi
@Serializable(with = EventSerializer::class)
sealed class Event {
    val eventName: String? = null
    val productName: String? = null
}
```

I have three subclasses

```
@Serializable
class EventFailure : Event()
@Serializable
class EventSuccess : Event()
@Serializable
class EventInvalid : Event()
```

and this is the Serializer

```
@ExperimentalSerializationApi
@Serializer(forClass = Event::class)
object EventSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<Event>(Event::class) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<out Event> {
        return element.jsonObject["eventName"]?.jsonPrimitive?.content?.let {
            when (EventType.valueOf(it)) {
                EventType.FAILURE -> EventFailure.serializer()
                EventType.SUCCESS -> EventSuccess.serializer()
            }
        } ?: EventInvalid.serializer()
    }
}
```

When I deserialize a JSON list, all the values end up null:

```
val events = JSON.decodeFromString<Array<Event>>(it.body())

events.forEach {
    println(it)
    println(it.productName)
}
```

```
com.blah.EventSuccess@2ca132ad
null
com.blah.EventFailure@1686f0b4
null
```

If I change Event from a sealed class to a normal class without the custom serializer, data correctly deserializes into the Even class filling in all the values.

Any suggestions on how to make the deserialization into EventSuccess / EventFailure work correctly?

Comment: You might need to enable [array polymorphism](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx.serialization.json/-json-builder/#-917438954%2FProperties%2F-702380584)

Comment: I've tried enabling that without success. I did get success using a custom classDiscriminator, but still curious how one can fix the custom serializer

Comment: `productName` is null because that's the default value set `Event`. There's no way to create an `Event` that doesn't have a null product name (either in regular code, or in Kotlinx Serialization). [Properties must be in the constructor](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/basic-serialization.md#constructor-properties-requirement).

Answer (score 0):

I made a custom JSON class with custom classDiscriminator

```
    companion object {
        val JSON = Json {
            prettyPrint = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            encodeDefaults = true
            classDiscriminator = "eventName"
        }
    }
```

```
@Serializable
@SerialName("SUCCESS")
class EventSuccess : Event()
@Serializable
@SerialName("FAILURE")
class EventFailure : Event()
```

and I removed the custom serializer

```
//@Serializable(with = EventSerializer::class)
@Serializable
sealed class Event {
```

and it's working correctly now.

I'm keeping the question open to see if there are perhaps ways of fixing the custom serializer implementation.